# How to cycle all ShapeRange collection in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, collections

Here is an image to explain what i need.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efeG8.png)

I am having hard time figuring how to do `for each aShpRg in ActiveSheet` stuff.. where aShpRg is a ShapeRange object

Ultimately, I want to lock the aspect ration of many images inside comments so they do not get distorted by Excel when inserting, moving, and deleting columns...

Your help will be much appreciated

This is giving me errors:

```
Dim aShpRg As ShapeRange
For Each aShpRg In ActiveSheet.ShapeRange
aShpRg.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
Next aShpRg
```

Comment: Placed code in code sample, i = I

Comment: you must loop through worksheet `Comments` collection and act on each comment `Shape` property - see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited: after understanding OP's real need

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim com As Comment

    For Each com In ActiveSheet.Comments
        com.Shape.Placement = xlFreeFloating
    Next com
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this has no effect, as it just changes the aspect ratio in the "size" tab, not the "picture aspect ratio" when one goes deeper into the image inside a comment. I am coming into the conclusion that this is impossible with VBA, as i recorded a macro to do it, and Excel even refuses to replay it, giving an error!

Comment: Dear SIr, I am afraid this is not it. So I added an image to my post (first sentence link) so you can see what I am trying to do. PS i think it is not achievable, so i will implement an additional task to the macro that created the image: to write in the comment the size of the original picture. So a "Cleaning Macro" would just read the note and resize images accordingly! Yet to do...

Comment: Yes, Excel 2003. Ok it gets the comments back to their positions, near the cell, but it does not correct the distortion in the image aspect ratio itself...

Comment: Finally i understand that this answer is a Pre-emptive one, so the problem won't happen once again.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Thanks for your feedback